# How to disable inline css styles generated by Gutenberg editor?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, api, genesis-theme-framework

I've got Genesis-blocks plugin installed (it got updated from Atomic blocks). I am using *blocks* and *resuable blocks* to create pages. The problem I am facing is, most of these blocks inject their own inline styling, e.g. `button` block creates an anchor tag, but it gives inline styling for background-color and text-color as well.

Doing my own research I found that the default appearance of these blocks can be edited with [javascript api](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/), but the docs don't tell which javascript file to use. That is, all this jsx code, where am supposed to put this? Am I supposed to create a new plugin? Obviously js code won't go in `functions.php` and I don't really think it is going into my theme's `main.js` file as well because that is going to be loaded for the end user not the `wp-admin`. The only way I found to do this is somewhat done here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/  but I need more explanation to this, is `render_block` triggered every time a block is rendered on the front end? Are `$block_content` and  `$block` passed by `render_block` internally?

There's some more documentation that suggest changing `theme.json` file, but I am using wordpress 5.8, which has `version:1` for `theme.json` file and the docs don't any example on that.

**Question:** So, can I access similar functions to js api in my functions.php file or if js is the only way, which js file am I supposed to use? Also, is it possible to disable all inline styles generated by the gutenburg block editor and genesis blocks?